# Too many login attempts-autobanned from my own site

Tags: login

I mistyped my username and password too many times and now receive the 403: Access Forbidden
Too many login attempts (Autobanned) whenever I try to login or even view the websites. Any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: This is most likely coming from a 3rd party extensions. Do you have something like `RS Firewall` installed?

Comment: Yes. Should I disable that?

Comment: As you isolate relevant details associated with your problem, please edit your question to express the "full story". Stating the existence of specific extensions will be valuable to volunteers and should be stated as a question edit instead of a comment.  Ideally, pages should have as few comments as possible. That said, it is great that you replied to Lodder with requested/vital diagnostic details.

Comment: Related resource found while Googling: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=865462

Answer (score 0):

See this link: https://www.siteground.com/kb/i_cant_log_into_the_joomla_backend_as_administrator/

If you are using Admin Tools, you can reset your access by using the link that displays (replace the email address), follow this example:
https://www.akeeba.com/videos/1207-admin-tools/1551-at009-unblocking-yourself.html

Comment: Thank you again for contributing. There is some vital guidance that I need to offer.  On all Stack Exchange sites, answers can be supported by off-site resources, but the crux of the resolving advice should be hardcoded into the answer. The reason for this is because hyperlinks are prone to breakage (if the site goes away or if the document path changes).  If both hyperlinks died, your answer would not be very helpful. Please edit your answer to express the solution as text. It is fine to copy-paste from other resources -- just remember to give attribution and use quote block formatting.